# How to move a matrix

Tags: java, matrix, jframe, keyevent

I´m new to Java, and I´m working with a school project.

In this project I have to create a matrix using a KeyListener.
I made it like so:

```
    if (!(e.getKeyChar()>='0' && e.getKeyChar()<='9' || e.getKeyChar()=='-'  || e.getKeyCode()==10) ) {
        if(!(e.getKeyChar() == 'w' || e.getKeyChar() == 'b')){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(lince, "Not Allowed", "Fatal Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }else{
        if(e.getKeyCode()==10){
            try{    
                MatrixI[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(Posicion);
                j++;
                Posicion = "";
        if (j== 4){
                i++; 
                j=0;   
        }if (i==5){
            if (!(i >= 6)){      
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(lince, "You cannot add more numbers", "Not Allowed!!!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                contar();
            }
        }      
            }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(lince, "You cannot add more numbers", "Not Allowed!!!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(lince, "Just write a number", "Not Allowed!!!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }else{
            Posicion=Posicion+e.getKeyChar();
            this.escribe(lince.getGraphics());
        }
    }


public void escribe(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.CENTER_BASELINE,12));
    g.drawString(Posicion, 30+((1+j)*50),((1+i)*35));
}
```

This part prints the matrix but it is not in a good position and I want to move it.

[image]

Does anybody have any idea?
How can I move it?

Comment: `Graphics#drawString(String, int, int)` where the `int` values are x/y ... try changing the `y` value

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change this line of code:

```
  g.drawString(Posicion, 30+((1+j)*50),((1+i)*35));
```

DrawString takes what you want to write as the first parameter and then x and y coordinates. So, for example if you want to move it up, subtract something to the y coord.

Comment: *"if you want to move it up, add something to the y coord"* - 2D Graphics works in top/left coordinate space (0x0 is top left), so if you want to move something up, you would need to subtract from the y coord

Comment: You are right. I've fixed my answer. Thank you for your feedback!